# Query to get MAX value and corresponding date

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table**

```
+---------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+----------+
| timestamp           | hostname                    | LICENSECOUNT | MAX_USED |
+---------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+----------+
| 2021-02-03 17:00:03 | server1                     |          125 |      10  |
| 2021-02-03 17:00:06 | server2                     |          415 |      50  |
| 2021-02-26 18:00:07 | server1                     |          125 |      125 |
| 2021-02-26 18:00:09 | server2                     |          415 |      415 |
| 2021-03-05 17:00:02 | server1                     |          125 |      115 |
| 2021-03-05 17:00:04 | server2                     |          415 |      315 |
```

**My query** - Get the max value for license count grouped by server in the past 30 days

```sql
select 
    timestamp, hostname, LICENSECOUNT, max(currentused) as MAX_USED 
from 
    LICENSECHECKS 
where 
    TIMESTAMP BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() 
group by hostname;
```

**My result** - The timestamp is the start of the dataset (30 days ago)

```
+---------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+----------+
| timestamp           | hostname                    | LICENSECOUNT | MAX_USED |
+---------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+----------+
| 2021-02-03 17:00:03 | server1                     |          125 |      125 |
| 2021-02-03 17:00:06 | server2                     |          415 |      415 |
```

**My Desired Result** - The timestamps are corresponding to the dates which

```
+---------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+----------+
| timestamp           | hostname                    | LICENSECOUNT | MAX_USED |
+---------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+----------+
| 2021-02-26 18:00:07 | server1                     |          125 |      125 |
| 2021-02-26 18:00:09 | server2                     |          415 |      415 |
```

Answer (score 0):

In a sub-query select statement add the following

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hostname ORDER BY currentuserid DESC) as RN
```

Then pull the row(s) with RN = 1 in the outer query where statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select lc.*
    timestamp, hostname, LICENSECOUNT, max(currentused) as MAX_USED 
from LICENSECHECKS 
where lc.currentused = (select max(lc2.currentused)
                        from licensechecks lc2
                        where lc2.timestamp >= now() - interval 30 day and
                              lc2.hostname = lc.hostname
                       );
```

Notes:

- This assumes no future `timestamps`.
- This will return duplicates if there are duplicate max values (which can be handled with a tweak).
- `now()` has a time component.  I suspect that you might want something like `curdate() - interval 29 day`.